# How to get Helios and Rails to work together (Rack issues)?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rack

I'm trying to get Helios (https://github.com/helios-framework/helios) to work with an existing Ruby on Rails 3.1 application. But there's a conflict regarding `rack` version; `bundle install` gives me this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    helios (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4) ruby

    rails (>= 3.1) ruby depends on
      rack (1.3.9)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Work-around: I thought Helios was a prerequisite to implement iOS AFIncrementalStore on a Rails app (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app), but it isn't. The iOS app seems to run fine with my "vanilla" Rails app serving JSON.